# How to add default text to select option using Knockout

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Title says it all, I haven't found anything on this yet and wondering if it's possible. I'm trying to make a select option look like the following:

```
<option>Last 'knockout variable' Days</option>
```

Knockout will bind the option text no problem which is currently 30 or 60... etc. but I need default text around that option.

I made a non working jfiddle so you can kind of see what my code looks like.
http://jsfiddle.net/RBx6h/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use function to define option text

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: activityFilters, 
    optionsText: function(item) { 
        return 'Last ' + item + ' Days';
    }, 
    value: selectedActivityFilter">
</select>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55aDa/)**

Options binding [tutorial](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html), example 4, represents drop-down with displayed text computed as a function of the represented item

Comment: Thank you! completely forgot I can do that.